# Diffrent component with text based on the condition xml design in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create the form in android as shown in the image below. What is the best approach to create this type of form in android.How can I achieve this type of form in android xml design. The components are not static components they are dynamic. I need to add all dynamic components.

There may be a need to perform validation on field.

[image]

Comment: Use `Linear Layout` with `Vertical` Orientation.

Comment: Yes, you must use linear layout by use of gravity and weightsum concept

Comment: how can i added components . they are not static components they are dynamic .

Answer (score 0):

> Use **GridLayout** to achieve this type of layout. You can give the text as your own wish.

For ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4" >

    <TextView
        android:text="1,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="1,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="1,3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="1,4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2,3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="2,4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,3 longer" />

    <TextView
        android:text="3,4" />

    <TextView
        android:text="4,1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="4,2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="4,3" />

    <TextView
        android:text="4,4" />

</GridLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The row count and column count will be dynamic in my form how to achieve this.

Comment: Simple, create textview in programmatically and add that view into the gridlayout.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to take a Scroll View with LinearLayout as its child, give it an id say mLinearLayout. Using that id you can add n number of views to that layout.

Sample way to add layout to linear layout programmatically, suppose you have taken

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Now, to add a view programmatically to the linear layout, say you want to add a TextView to the Linear Layout, then

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Hello World!");
textView.setId(5);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
mLinearLayout.addView(textView);
```

Comment: Can you please show me how can I add textview with edittext and radio checkbox  at the same line.